# How many days has bitcoin reached "all time high" in the first 3 quarters of 2017?

Tags: price-volatility

From Jan 1 2017 to Oct 1 2017 makes around 275 days. How many of these days did the BTC price reach an all-time-high?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you can simply check this by looking at BTC price charts which are available on a multitude of bitcoin websites.

Comment: There are plenty of interesting question which can be simply answered by looking at readily-available information - if you know where to look. I don't think this is reason for closing, but perhaps an answer should focus on where the find the information rather than just a number.

Comment: Agree with @PieterWuille, I don't think this should be closed